# php GD image showing something with text

Tags: php, image, gd

I am trying to make signature it working correct but in someusers it show after text "r"
ex: http://grabcnr.net/sign/goldzoro
however  http://grabcnr.net/sign/bangobng, some users work correct

Full code

http://pastebin.com/Dk2u83JV

```
<?php

$user = $_GET['user'];
$user = strtolower($user);
$player = $user;
$hits = file_get_contents("http://grabcnr.net/adminsys/grabdatabase.php?pass=grabapi1&user=$player&f=sighits");
$arrests = file_get_contents("http://grabcnr.net/adminsys/grabdatabase.php?pass=grabapi1&user=$player&f=sigarrests");
$arrested = file_get_contents("http://grabcnr.net/adminsys/grabdatabase.php?pass=grabapi1&user=$player&f=sigarrested");
$robs = file_get_contents("http://grabcnr.net/adminsys/grabdatabase.php?pass=grabapi1&user=$player&f=sigrobs");
$robbed = file_get_contents("http://grabcnr.net/adminsys/grabdatabase.php?pass=grabapi1&user=$player&f=sigrobbed");
$score = file_get_contents("http://grabcnr.net/adminsys/grabdatabase.php?pass=grabapi1&user=$player&f=sigscore");
$lotto = file_get_contents("http://grabcnr.net/adminsys/grabdatabase.php?pass=grabapi1&user=$player&f=siglotto");
$mb = file_get_contents("http://grabcnr.net/adminsys/grabdatabase.php?pass=grabapi1&user=$player&f=sigmb");
$plate = file_get_contents("http://grabcnr.net/adminsys/grabdatabase.php?pass=grabapi1&user=$player&f=sigplate");
$hits = str_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$hits);


$plate = strip_tags($plate);

header('Content-Type: image/png'); 

$image = imagecreatefrompng("sig.png");


$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$whitesemi  = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255, 255, 255, 60);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 165,10,10);


 $a1 = "hits Done:$hits";
//choose a default php font number 1 to 5
$font = 2;

imagestring($image, 5, 90, 4, "$user", $red); 
imagestring($image, 3, 10, 25, "$a1", $white); 
imagestring($image, 3, 10, 40, "Arrests:$arrests", $white); 
imagestring($image, 3, 10, 55, "Arrested:$arrested", $white); 
imagestring($image, 3, 10, 70, "Robs:$robs", $white); 
imagestring($image, 3, 10, 85, "Robbed:$robbed", $white); 
imagestring($image, 3, 130, 25, "Score:$score", $white); 
imagestring($image, 3, 130, 40, "Lotto Won:$lotto", $white); 
imagestring($image, 3, 130, 55, "Money Bags:$mb", $white); 
imagestring($image, 3, 130, 70, "Plate:$plate", $white); 
imagestring($image, 3, 130, 85, "www.grabcnr.net", $whitesemi); 
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);



?>
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: You most likely have an `\r` in your code. Show us what you're using; we can't "guess".

Comment: okay sorry here you go

Comment: Maybe your DB (or file) contains a quote or strange character. It's really hard (for me) to say. If your code here works for one but not another, then I doubt the problem is in your (posted) code.

Comment: http://grabcnr.net/adminsys/grabdatabase.php?pass=grabapi1&user=goldzoro&f=sigmb database api working normal , it does not show any other character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query to check whether there are possible \r or \r\n in your data:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "\r\n";
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "\r";
```

If you find any any then you have to replace it.

Comment: Did you checked mysql data.I checked the 2 ex you have given using inspect element on chrome browser. In 1st ex there is line break while in other there is none.

Comment: Call one of your api for both the example you will find line break in 1st but not in second. So check your mysql data or use str_replace in php

Comment: oh sorry i was editing wrong file thank you it works !